# Place innerHTML in element as a text not html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building messenger app using AngularJS .
**messagesData** is an array that contains message type and message content and sent by who .

When I use this function it works perfect ,

But when I type any html code in the function the html get applied in the message box

Example :

`input("<div>Hello</div>")`

it creates a div inside of it the hello word but I want the whole element to appear in the message

This is the function that i'm talking about :

```
function dataToHtml(which){
            //check if data = message
            if(messagesData[which][0]=='message'){
                //check if its user message or the other one
                if(messagesData[which][1]=='mine'){
                    chatContainer.innerHTML+=
                    `
                    <div class="chat-message-box">
                        <div class="mine-message chat-message">${messagesData[which][2]}</div>
                    </div>
                    `
                }else if(messagesData[which][1]=='other'){
                    chatContainer.innerHTML+=
                    `
                    <div class="chat-message-box">
                        <div class="other-message chat-message main-bg">${messagesData[which][2]}</div>
                    </div>
                    `
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: 1. `const div = document.createElement('div');` 2. `div.classList.add('chat-message-box');` 3. `div.innerHTML = "<div ...></div>";` 4. `div.querySelector('chat-message').innerText = messagesData[which][2];` 5. `chatContainer.append(div);`

Answer (score 1):

Use one way flow syntax property binding:

```
comment: string;
comment = "<p><em><strong>abc</strong></em></p>";
<div [innerHTML]="comment"></div>
```

From angular docs: "Angular recognizes the value as unsafe and automatically sanitizes it, which removes the  tag but keeps safe content such as the  element."
https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example